# How to locally test open graph metadata preview in social chat apps like skype, whatsapp, telegram and discord?

Tags: angular, testing, localhost, metadata, preview

I am going to locally test open graph on social chatting apps in development environment.

But I have some issues.
I tried using ngrok and localtunnel, but they are not working. Social chatting apps did display no metadata from the link generated by ngrok and localtunnel.

I develop web app using Angular 12 and set metadata using Angular meta service.

How can I locally test metadata on social apps?

Answer (score -1):

The chrome extension will host the meta tags on a domain and gives you the link to share. If you also want to test local images try uploading in  postimages or imgbb first.

I built this to share links and test yourselves in social medias.  [Localhost open graph tester](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/localhost-open-graph-test/nggoiohoonibebildpjhlaakfoccpfln)